Compare two columns with duplicates in first column and highlight matches
Team,
I bummed on how to do this. I need to compare two columns.
Col F with source column P and highlight the matches in Col F including the duplicates if any. Since both columns has duplicates within themselves, i cannot use highlight duplicates using conditional formatting.
Appreciate your help.
File


If you want a cell in column F to be highlighted if its value appears anywhere in column P, use conditional formatting with the following formula: =COUNTIF(P:P,F2)>0

Not sure what you're after, but maybe =IFNA(MATCH(P2,F$1:F$100,0),"") not using conditional formatting, but adding a column using this formula will return the row number of the matching value in column F which  I think may be useful to you. (adjust the range size to your needs).
